# Make indexing of values in column

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "B2",
"B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2"), operation = c("open",
"open", "close", "", "open", "close", "", "open", "open", "open",
"close", "upload", "open", "close", "open", "close")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-16L))
```

```
ID      operation
A1       open
A1       open
A1       close
A1       
A1       open
A1       close
B2      
B2       open
B2       open
B2       open
B2       close
B2       upload
B2       open
B2       close
B2       open
B2       close
```

I want to add index for each bundle of "open" and "close" in column operation. So for each row between open and close must have same index. So desired result is:

```
ID      operation    index
A1       open         1
A1       open         1
A1       close        1
A1       
A1       open         2
A1       close        2
B2      
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       close        3
B2       upload
B2       open         4
B2       close        4
B2       open         5
B2       close        5
```

I do it like this:

```
dt[, index := .GRP, by = .(rev(cumsum(rev(operation) == 'close')))]
dt[, index := ifelse(cumsum(operation == 'open') > 0, index, NA), by = .(ID, index)]
```

However I want there be two options for "close". It can be "close" or it can be "checking":

```
ID      operation
A1       open
A1       open
A1       checking
A1       
A1       open
A1       close
B2      
B2       open
B2       open
B2       open
B2       close
B2       upload
B2       open
B2       close
B2       open
B2       close
```

and i want to get:

```
ID      operation    index
A1       open         1
A1       open         1
A1       checking     1
A1       
A1       open         2
A1       close        2
B2      
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       open         3
B2       close        3
B2       upload
B2       open         4
B2       close        4
B2       open         5
B2       close        5
```

How could I add this or option?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `%in%` to check for multiple values.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)
dt[, index := .GRP, by = .(rev(cumsum(rev(operation) %in% c('close', 'checking'))))]
dt[, index := ifelse(cumsum(operation == 'open') > 0, index, NA), by = .(ID, index)]
```